# EJB remote JNDI binding on weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have a simple remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface MainDaoEJBRemote {

    void sayHelloRemote();

}
```

And I have a `Stateless` EJB that implements my interface:

```
    @Stateless(mappedName = "MainDaoEJB")
    @Remote
    public class MainDaoEJB implements MainDaoEJBRemote {

        @Override
        public void sayHelloRemote() {

            System.out.println("remote invoked...");

        } 
    }
```

I have deployed it to a `weblogic` server.

I have a `ManagedBean` and I'm trying to lookup for the remote `EJB` This is my lookup part:

```
public void sayHello() throws NamingException {
    System.out.println("invoked...");
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "t3://127.0.0.1:7001");
    env.put("java.naming.security.principal", "user");
    env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "pass");
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
    try {
        MainDaoEJBRemote mainDaoEJB
                = (MainDaoEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("MainDaoEJB");
        System.out.println("invoked... " + mainDaoEJB.toString());
        mainDaoEJB.sayHelloRemote();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("NamingException: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());   
        }
    }

}
```

When i try to invoked my `sayHello()` method at the managedBean it throws `NamingException`: Unable to resolve 'MainDaoEJB'. Resolved ''

Can you tell me how to look up my remote `EJB` properly? Should I set up the `JNDI` name of my `EJB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remote lookup on WebLogic you should use JNDI name `MainDaoEJB#<package>.MainDaoEJBRemote`

```
MainDaoEJBRemote mainDaoEJB
            = (MainDaoEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("MainDaoEJB#<package>.MainDaoEJBRemote")
```